# Where is Esty sleeping at the end of Episode 1?

Tags: unorthodox

At the end of episode 1 of Unorthodox, Esty is seen sleeping in what looks like some sort of classroom. Where is is this place? How did she find a place to sleep in Germany?

[image: Room where Etsy sleeps]